# Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers: "invalid arguments" error displayed by mistake?

Tags: c++, eclipse-cdt

I'm getting an error of invalid arguments in the Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers Photon (4.8.0) at `map_name.insert(make_pair("string_name", int_name);`.

I am using GCC 8.2.0. I'm trying some simple stuff with STL.

Tried either both `insert(make_pair())` or `insert(pair<string, int>())` getting same IDE error(Semantic error). Why is that?

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    map<string, int> ages;

    ages["Mike"] = 21;
    ages["Johnny"] = 20;
    ages["Vicky"] = 30;
    ages["Mike"] = 42;

//  ages.insert(make_pair("Peter", 100));
    ages.insert(pair < string, int > ("Peter", 100));

    for(map<string, int>::iterator it = ages.begin(); it!=ages.end(); it++)
    {
        cout<< it->first<<": "<< it->second<<endl;

    }

     return (0);
}
```

This is the error that is displayed in the IDE:

[image: Error]

Comment: Compiles and runs fine on OS X command line

Comment: Maybe its the IDE, what to know how to fix it in eclipse.

Comment: Can you please post the full error message? The code compiles fine on GCC 8.2 ([see](https://godbolt.org/z/3cuxkb))

Comment: @HenriqueJung I added a picture in the original post, its a squiggly red line below insert function.

Comment: I think this is just a bug in Eclipse in-editor parsing, that most likely performs a lot of heuristics to be responsive. Have you tried compiling it using a command line? Maybe just triggering a "build" button on Eclipse will make the error go away.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The standard library implementation that ships with GCC 8 uses a type trait intrinsic called `__is_constructible`, which Eclipse CDT's parser does not yet support.

This can result in false positive errors when CDT is made to parse GCC 8's standard library code.

If you use GCC 7 or earlier, you don't get any errors for this code.

**UPDATE**: [This eclipse bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=539052) tracks adding support for `__is_constructible` to CDT's parser. It has recently been fixed, though the fix has not appeared in a CDT release yet.